# How to transfer Javascript code correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, canvasjs

I have two codes, both generate a line chart. However, the first one doesn't use mysql datasource, it uses random math generated datapoints. But it uses a refresh interval and thus is live.

The second code does in fact use a mysql datasource and displays the data in my database in the line-chart. However it is not live, because it does not it has not refresh-interval function.

I was trying to transfer the refresh-Interval / chart-update code parts of the first code  to my second code that is not live but uses a real data source.

**Here is my live code, with random datapoints:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">` 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {

            var dps = []; // dataPoints

            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2",{
                title :{
                    text: "Patient #01"
                },          
                data: [{
                    type: "line",
                    dataPoints: dps 
                }]
            });

            var xVal = 0;
            var yVal = 100; 
            var updateInterval = 20;
            var dataLength = 500; // number of dataPoints visible at any point

            var updateChart = function (count) {
                count = count || 1;
                // count is number of times loop runs to generate random dataPoints.

                for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {   
                    yVal = yVal +  Math.round(5 + Math.random() *(-5-5));
                    dps.push({
                        x: xVal,
                        y: yVal
                    });
                    xVal++;
                };
                if (dps.length > dataLength)
                {
                    dps.shift();                
                }

                chart.render();     

            };

            // generates first set of dataPoints
            updateChart(dataLength); 

            // update chart after specified time. 
            setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval); 

        }

    </script>
```

**This is my code of the static line chart (not live) but uses real data source:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">` 
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

                    $().ready(function () {

                    $.getJSON("arduino_data.php", function (result) {

                    var dataPoints = [];

                    for (var i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
                    dataPoints.push({ x: Number(result[i].x), y: Number(result[i].y) });
                    }

                    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
                title :{
                    text: "Patient #01"
                },          
                data: [{
                    type: "line",
                    dataPoints: dataPoints 
                }]
            });

                    chart.render();
                    });

            });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>
```

**This is what I have tried so far:**

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

                $().ready(function () {

                    $.getJSON("arduino_data.php", function (result) {

                var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
                title :{
                text: "Patient #01"
                },          
                data: [{
                type: "line",
                dataPoints: dataPoints 
                }]
                });

                var dataPoints = [];
                var updateInterval = 20;
                var dataLength = 500; // number of dataPoints visible at any point

                var updateChart = function (count) {
                          count = count || 1;

                for (var i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
                dataPoints.push({ x: Number(result[i].x), y: Number(result[i].y) });
                };

               }
                if (dataPoints.length > dataLength)
                {
                dataPoints.shift();             
                }

                chart.render();     

        )};

        // generates first set of dataPoints
        updateChart(dataLength); 

        // update chart after specified time. 
        setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval); 


       }




</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width:100%;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But it keeps saying

> Unexpected token ')' at line 42

```
            chart.render();     

    )};
```

I am pretty embarrassed but I can't find the solution due to all the bracelets/parenthesizes. I have tried everything. With ) and without } but nothing seems to deliver.

If this is solved, will the chronological positions of the code be alright?

**EDIT: FIRST PROBLEM SOLVED, NEW PROBLEM: JS POSITIONING**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

                $().ready(function () {

                    $.getJSON("arduino_data.php", function (result) {

                var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
                title :{
                text: "Patient #01"
                },          
                data: [{
                type: "line",
                dataPoints: dataPoints 
                }]
                });

                var dataPoints = [];
                var updateInterval = 20;
                var dataLength = 500; // number of dataPoints visible at any point

                var updateChart = function (count) {
                          count = count || 1;

                for (var i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
                dataPoints.push({ x: Number(result[i].x), y: Number(result[i].y) });
                };

               }
                if (dataPoints.length > dataLength)
                {
                dataPoints.shift();             
                }

                chart.render();     

                });

        // generates first set of dataPoints
        updateChart(dataLength); 

        // update chart after specified time. 
        setInterval(updateChart, updateInterval); 


       });




</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width:100%;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

output:

> Can't find variable: updateChart

Comment: You say that you cannot locate the line 42? If you indent properly your JS those errors would be trivial to find even in Notepad.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, line 42 is at:  chart.render(); )};         whatever I change there, it won't work

Comment: `chart.render(); )};` last should be `});` and after `setInterval();` there should be the same `});`

Comment: Thanks it worked. but now it says (what I was afraid of due to the positioning): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: updateChart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `)};` instead of `});`

also at the end of your JS you used only `}` instead of `});`

also call your chart like

```
setInterval(updateChart, updateInterval);
```

and make sure your `updateInterval` is in the right function scope.
Here's how it should approximately look like:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    function updateChart( result ) { // move it here!!!
        $.getJSON("arduino_data.php", function( result ){
            var dataPoints = [];
            var dataLength = 500; // number of dataPoints visible at any point
            var updateInterval = 1000;
            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{ // new chart Object
                title :{
                    text: "Patient #01"
                },          
                data: [{
                    type: "line",
                    dataPoints: dataPoints 
                }]
            });
            for (var i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
                dataPoints.push({ x: Number(result[i].x), y: Number(result[i].y) });
            }
            if (dataPoints.length > dataLength){
                dataPoints.shift();             
            }        
            chart.render();   
        }); 
    }


    // First read - Start
    updateChart(); 
    // Update chart after specified time. 
    setInterval(updateChart, updateInterval); 

});
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I have been looking at it too long, to oversee this.. It now says: Thanks it worked. but now it says (what I was afraid of due to the positioning): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: updateChart  this is what my main question was actually, because i am new to javascript. I have noticed that positioning is rather important with JS

Comment: @MieerDarwesh ohh yes cause you need to create your function outside your scope of the getJson

Comment: @MieerDarwesh just a question... what should the interval actually do? Ping every n time the arduino data?

Comment: exactly!  Every time my pulse sensor gives new data to a textfile which is caught into my DB, it should be displayed without refresh with JSON data fetching.

Comment: Your code has solved the can't find variable issue. It now says the same about the variable dataLenght and and more tricky one: updateChart.

Comment: So I moved dataLength to outside of the scope, so this one is done. No only updateChart left

Comment: See the `count` argument? You set it always to 1 but you never use that count argument variable

Comment: Well I thought it would be used, just like in the initial live code.

Comment: @MieerDarwesh updated my answer. This might not work as expected, since I don't know what's returned, but you got the principle. The function now encapslates all the work that has to be done on the first run and every n time.

Comment: @MieerDarwesh I believe that you can keep the chart Object instance outside that function, but again... I cannot test.